# Ionic can't open webpage in system browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open the system web browser to a specific page, but I can't get it working at all. I've installed `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1`, and to open the system browser I make the following call `window.open("https://google.com","_system")`. What happens is that first nothing happens, and after a couple of seconds the page is shown on top of my app (within the app) with no possibility to close the page. How do I open the system browser instead of opening the link within the same app?

Comment: Maybe you could try use `cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://google.com","_system", 'location=yes')` in device ready callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.openWebBrowser = function() {
    var iabRef = null;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Global InAppBrowser reference
    function iabLoadStart(event) {
        // alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadStop(event) {
        // alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        // spinnerplugin.hide();
    }

    function iabLoadError(event) {
        // alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
    }

    function iabClose(event) {
        // alert(event.type);
        iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
        iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
        iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
        iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // spinnerplugin.show();
        // var sedlId = localStorage.getItem('sedlId');
        // var userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        // iabRef = window.open('http://xyz/xyz.php?schedule_id=' + sedlId + '&user_id=' + userId + '', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
        iabRef = window.open('http://xyz/xyz.php?', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
        iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
        iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
        iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
        iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
            // var checkurlstring = event.url;
            // var checkbookid = checkurlstring.substring(20, 100);
            // localStorage.setItem('bookId', checkbookid);

            if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
                iabRef.close();
                // $state.go('app.bordingUserPg');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a cordova app as well. I also have cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (1.2.1) added.
With this plugin, you can open

> standard pages like "www.google.com" by calling
>
> ```
> window.open("www.google.com", "_system", "location=yes");
> ```
>
> social media pages like facebook, twitter, etc. after an app-availabilty check

With the aforementioned command, the app opens the link in a new window/tab of my browser.

Where did you test your code? In a browser on your pc or on an actual device? Does the device have a functioning browser-app installed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your problem is solved, and I'm using it in my project recently.

1. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (version is 1.4.0);
2. controller：window.open(partInfo.partner.link, '_system', 'location=yes');
3. check on android.json and config.xml files whether success to configration after install;
4. also, if you build project though Android Studio, you'd better to check this plugin in Android -> java -> org.apache.cordova

Comment: partInfo.partner.link is your target link